# How to add collaborators to openshift git repo

Tags: git, openshift

I have an **application** set up in redhat openshift and are able to commits and push.

My question is, how do I include my teammates into this repository so that they can do the same as well.

New to git and openshift. Help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, anyone? If my question is unclear;please do tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add their SSH Public keys to your the application through the web console or the command line tools. In the command line it is rhc-sshkey.

Once those keys are added your other developers should be able to use the same git commands (over SSH) that you use to interact with the repo.

"rhc app show" should give you the SSH git url.

Answer (score 2):

Following step by step instructions from the below link would help:

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/managing-multiple-ssh-keys-on-openshift